# Is it possible to divide a redis cluster on ElastiCache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster, amazon-elasticache

I currently have various clients and various redis clusters on aws, on for each client. But I would like to know if it's possible to divide de redis cluster so I can use, let's say, one redis cluster for a lot of clients. Each client has its own server that uses the cache independently, and if they were in the same cluster, they probably would have keys with the same name and might be in conflict. So in this scenario my questions are:

Is it possible to divide the redis cluster for use different parts of it isolated from the others ? I think this is different from shards.

How would I avoid the probable conflict described above ?

Comment: Redis supports up to 16 databases by default, which is also true on elasticache. When you connect to redis, you connect to database "0" by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to achieve protection against key name collisions you can use multiple approaches.

If you are using none cluster mode Redis then you can configure each client to use different database as described [here](https://redis.io/commands/select/). Please note that if you suspect you might need to scale out in the future then multiple databases are not supported by Redis. This would be a reason to start with other options.

You can use {tags} as described [here](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/#:%7E:text=of%20this%20document.-,Hash%20tags,-There%20is%20an). The tag could be the name of your client or anything else which you want to use to group all keys on the same slot for multi key operations. This will also promise that key {client1}key1 will not collide with key {client2}key1. This approach will work for both cluster mode enabled and cluster mode disabled clusters so it is future proof if you will need to scale out.